How to display leaf packages
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS or later
I want to get all LEAF packages (top dependencies).
Purpose: cleaning system from packages I don't need.
It's hard to search through full list apt list --installed.
For me perfect list is filtered apt list.
Or any cli or graphical app to resolve this problem.
EDIT: It's not specific to list only manual installed. So it's not question "how to list manual installed packages"

The problem with this approach is meta-packages. Even utilities that you might not need are part of a meta-package, and thus listed as a dependency. Take the ubuntu-standard package for example. Do you need everything in there? Probably not, but some things are just nice to have.

My usual approach in cleaning up a system is to go through the installed packages section-by-section in aptitude, and mark packages as automatically installed if I think I don't need it. The libs section is the largest of these, and it is usually safe to set the entire section to auto-installed (by pressing M while the cursor is on the section header).

@ArturMeinild, Even if there are a lot of meta-packages I still want see list or packages that are required by anyone and also meta-packages. Is that possible?
I like using this technique in python with package pip3-autoremove. I always print pip-autoremove -ef to print all top packages  not required by anyone and also not required as extra for anyone

@SimonRichter Is that possible to show only not auto-installed in aptitude?

I have got an answer to question by myself.So I want to publish it but question is locked. CODE: installed_packages=$(dpkg -l 2>/dev/null | awk '/^.i/ {print $2}');manual_packages=$(apt list '~i !~E !~M' 2>/dev/null | awk -F'/' 'NR>1{print $1}');for p in $manual_packages; do     p_verified=$(apt-cache rdepends $p 2>/dev/null | tail -n+3 | awk '{$1=$1;print}' | grep -c -o -F -f <(echo "$installed_packages"));     if [ $p_verified -gt 0 ]; then         echo $p; fi; done It shows packages that are marked as MANUAL but are not LEAFS(required by someone)
After that you can apt-mark and clean.

"top dependencies" does not have the same definition to me in this context.
But leaf packages are usually all manually selected packages, the list can be long, but usually shorter. Try dpkg-query -W
you might also want to query packages by size, so you can focus on what is taking space on your harddrive.
see this other related question How do I list installed software with the installed size?
